# googlesheets - highlight cell if value contains in other sheets column

Tags: google-sheets

Say sheet1:

```
Id  Name2
1   orange
2   apple
3   pear
```

And sheet2:

```
Name1
This is apple  <-- should highlight
That is orange <-- should highlight
Give me a banana
pear <-- should highlight
```

I want to highlight sheet2 cell if contains sheet1 substring. I use below condition but only highlight the exact match one (pear)!

```
=match(A2,indirect("sheet1!B2:B"),0)
```

Please help suggest how to change it to highlight 1,2 and 4 since it contains substring from sheet1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("sheet1:B1:B"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but do not understand the reason use TEXTJOIN there,

Comment: @lucky1928 B1:B can have empty cells. 1 in 2nd textjoin parameter removes empty cells from range and joins non-empty cells with |

Answer (score 0):

In `Sheet2`

You can try:

Apply to range: `A1:A`

**Custom formula:**

```
=A1>INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!B2")
```